# psycopg2: can't connect DB! could not create socket: Too many open files

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I run a python script which do DB operations via psycopg2. But I'm facing the following error:

```
<class psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction>
can't connect DB! could not create socket: Too many open files
```

I actually also don't have *too many open files*, I close always the files after reading or writing and I even don't do too many file operations.

Here my code where I do file operations:

```
with open(config_path) as f:
     configs = json.load(f)
     return configs[name]
```

and here:

```
path = getmyPath()
    
if not os.path.isfile(path):
return None
    
with open(path) as f:
     data = f.read()
```

To solve the problem I always need to restart my script but it's in my case not a perfect solution, my script should be run for one month.

I also changed `ulimit` to `50000` but it still doesn't help me.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is my class for DB-Ops:

```
import psycopg2

class DBOps: 
    def __init__(self):
        conString = getCons() 
        try:
            self.connection = psycopg2.connect(conString)
            self.cr = self.connection.cursor()
        except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
            print("can't connect DB!", error)

    def select(self, query, onerow=False):
        self.cr.execute(query)
        records = self.cr.fetchall()
        if onerow:
            for row in records: 
                return row
        #self.cr.close()
        #self.connection.close()
        return records

    def exec(self, query):
        print(query)
        self.__init__()
        self.cr.execute(query)
        self.connection.commit()
        #self.cr.close()
        #self.connection.close()
        return self.cr.rowcount

    def close(self):
        self.cr.close()
        self.connection.close()
```

When I insert or make an update, I do following:

```
db = DBOps()
db.select(myQuery)
db.exec(myQuery)
```

Comment: You need to show us the code where you are opening and closing the files. It is possible that there is an error there that you have not picked up. I know you believe that could not possibly be true, because you say you don't have too many open files. But if it were my code, I would believe the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I just added my code

Comment: Notice that "files" don't just refer to actual disk files, but also to things like database connections and client/server connections — everything that is referred to by a file descriptor.

Comment: Is there a way to solve that problem?

Comment: I just added my code for DB operations. Do you think there is an issue with my code?

Comment: Do you ever call DBOps.close()?

Comment: No, I dont... :/

Comment: "strace" your process and see what files are getting opened.

Comment: How can I strace it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever call DBOps.close()? It might be a good idea to adopt the [resource manager protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) in the DBOps class and use a `with` statement.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/MNWvlp do you think it's a good idea?